# ASP.NET Core - Azure - WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved

Tags: asp.net-core, startup, azure-keyvault

Deploying my ASP.NET Core application to Microsoft Azure (pushing to Staging slot) is now starting to fail with the following error:

```
WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler+<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
```

This is happening during Startup, so was only detectable using DetailedErrors and CaptureStartupErrors.  From the longer Stack Trace, it looks like it is occurring after my AddKeyVault step, which is currently working in Production,  but when I try to push the updated bits, or the same code, I get that error.

I have tried pushing updated bits, creating a new Key Vault and switching to that URI, tried creating a new deployment slot in case it was corrupt for some reason, updated my whole solution from ASP.NET Core 1.1 to ASP.NET Core 2.0, all with the same error.

Has anyone run into an issue like this, or have a recommendation for further debugging?

Full Trace:

```
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential+<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient+<GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__66.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
 Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions+<GetSecretsAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider+<LoadAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList<IConfigurationProvider> providers)
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
Solution.Startup..ctor(IHostingEnvironment env) in Startup.cs
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider hostingServiceProvider, Type startupType, string environmentName)
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider+<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

My Startup.cs

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings();
    }

    var config = builder.Build();

    if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            config["AzureAd:BaseKeyVaultUri"],
            config["AzureAd:ClientId"],
            config["AzureAd:GraphClientSecret"]);
    }

    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
    this.CurrentEnvironment = env;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the Configuration for Startup
/// </summary>
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the Current Hosting Environment
/// </summary>
private IHostingEnvironment CurrentEnvironment { get; set; }

/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="services">Services to inject into or configure</param>
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(this.Configuration);

    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();

        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    services.AddMvc();

    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Audience = this.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
            options.Authority = string.Format(this.Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], this.Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
        })
        .AddAzureAd(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = this.Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
            options.AadInstance = this.Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"];
            options.Tenant = this.Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"];
            options.GraphClientSecret = this.Configuration["AzureAd:GraphClientSecret"];
            options.GraphResourceUri = this.Configuration["AzureAd:GraphResourceUri"];
        })
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        if (this.CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.ApprovalsPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireAssertion(e => true));
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.AdminPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireAssertion(e => true));
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.LTPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireAssertion(e => true));
        }
        else
        {
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.ApprovalsPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleConstants.ApprovalsRoleName));
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.AdminPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleConstants.AdminRoleName));
            options.AddPolicy(RoleConstants.LTPolicyName, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleConstants.LTRoleName));
        }

        // This policy ensures that applicable calls only come from the worker application.
        options.AddPolicy(
            RoleConstants.EmailRenderPolicyName,
            policy => policy.RequireClaim("appid", services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("Worker").GetValue<string>("ClientID")));
    });

    services.AddSession(o =>
    {
        o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    });

    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<AzureAdConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetChildren().First(c => c.Key.Equals("AzureAd")));
    services.Configure<NominationValidationOptions>(this.Configuration.GetChildren().First(c => c.Key.Equals("NominationValidationOptions")));
    services.Configure<EmailConfig>(this.Configuration.GetChildren().First(c => c.Key.Equals("Email")));
    services.Configure<FeatureConfig>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Features"));
    services.Configure<QueueConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Queue"));
    services.Configure<NominationConfiguration>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Nomination"));

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(this.CurrentEnvironment);
    services.AddTransient<IValidationService, NominationValidationService>();
    services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
    services.AddTransient<PraiseValidationService>();

    services.AddTransient<AuthenticationHelper>();
    services.AddTransient(sp =>
        new TokenAuthenticationHttpMessageHandler(
            new HttpClientHandler(),
            sp.GetRequiredService<AuthenticationHelper>(),
            this.Configuration["AzureAd:GraphResourceUri"]));
    services.AddTransient<IMicrosoftGraphHttpClient, MicrosoftGraphHttpClient>(sp =>
        new MicrosoftGraphHttpClient(
            new Uri(this.Configuration["AzureAd:GraphResourceUri"]),
            sp.GetRequiredService<TokenAuthenticationHttpMessageHandler>(),
            true));
    services.AddTransient<IMicrosoftGraphRepository, MicrosoftGraphRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IActiveDirectoryService, MicrosoftGraphService>();

    services.AddTransient<INominationService, NominationService>();
    services.AddTransient<INominationRepository>(_ => new NominationSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));
    services.AddTransient<INominationNoteRepository>(_ => new NominationNoteSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));
    services.AddTransient<IPraiseService, PraiseService>();
    services.AddTransient<IPraiseRepository>(_ => new PraiseSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));
    services.AddTransient<IRockstarService, RockstarService>();
    services.AddTransient<IRockstarRepository>(_ => new RockstarSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));

    services.AddTransient<IApprovalService, ApprovalService>();
    services.AddTransient<IApprovalRepository>(_ => new ApprovalSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));
    services.AddTransient<ILTService, LTService>();
    services.AddTransient<ILTApprovalRepository>(_ => new LTApprovalSqlRepository(_.GetService<SqlDatabase>()));
    services.AddTransient<ISiteContentService, SiteContentService>();
    services.AddTransient<ISiteContentRepository>((_) =>
    {
        var connectionString = this.Configuration["DefaultConnection"];
        return new SiteContentRepository(connectionString);
    });
    services.AddTransient<ITemplateService, RazorTemplateService>();
    services.AddTransient<ITemplateRepository>(_ => new TemplateFileRepository(@"Views\Template"));

    services.AddSingleton(sp => CloudStorageAccount.Parse(sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>().GetSection("Queue").GetValue<string>("StorageConnectionString")));
    services.AddSingleton(sp =>
    {
        var account = sp.GetRequiredService<CloudStorageAccount>();
        return account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    });
    services.AddTransient<IEmailQueueWriterService, EmailQueueWriterService>(sp =>
    {
        var client = sp.GetRequiredService<CloudQueueClient>();
        var queueName = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<QueueConfiguration>>().Value.EmailQueueName;
        var feedbackQueueName = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<QueueConfiguration>>().Value.FeedbackQueueName;

        var service = new EmailQueueWriterService(
            client.GetQueueReference(queueName),
            client.GetQueueReference(feedbackQueueName));
        return service;
    });
}

/// <summary>
/// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app">Application Builder</param>
/// <param name="env">Hosting Environment</param>
/// <param name="loggerFactory">Logging Factory</param>
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.IsAjaxRequest(), appBuilder =>
    {
        appBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("~/Error/{0}");
    });

    app.UseSecurityHeadersMiddleware();

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    var initalizer = new PropertyTelemetryInitializer(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
    var configuration = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<TelemetryConfiguration>();
    configuration.TelemetryInitializers.Add(initalizer);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I created a new AAD application and added that to Key Vault instead, and this worked.  There must have been an issue with the old AAD application because all I did was change the ClientID and it's now working.  I'm going to investigate this further.  Thanks Muneeb for your help.